# Input sanitization - Numeric values

Tags: oracle, validation, security, plsql, oracle11g

I've been asked to do input validation in order to prevent sql injection. I've been using dbms assert package functions to do the sanitization. However, when I try to sanitize a number(I'm getting it in varchar2(12 byte)) error is thrown. It's the same case with alphanumeric characters starting with number.

I tried various functions of dbms assert. Nothing seems to work except noop. But, noop is of no use since it does not do any validation.

```
create or replace procedure employee
(
v_emp_id IN varchar2(12 byte)
)
AS
lv_query CLOB;
BEGIN

if v_emp_id is NOT NULL THEN
lv_query := 'select * from employee where emp_id=''' || dbms_assert.enquote_name(v_emp_id) || '''';
--I also tried below:
-- lv_query := 'select * from employee where emp_id=''' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(v_emp_id) || '''';
end if;

END
```

No source gives more detailed input on dbms_assert package. Please help me in

1. Whether dbms_assert package can be used to sanitize numeric values(stored in VARCHAR2 variables). If yes, how?
2. Other ways of sanitizing input. (other than using bind variables)

Thanks.

Comment: Would help to show some of the code, no?

Comment: Which function did you use in that package? Provide some code you where you using that package and the returned errors will make your problem easier to solve.

Comment: Sure. I'll update the code in 15 mins. Thanks much

Comment: Hi @OldProgrammer I have updated a sample code.

Comment: Hi @tungns I have updated a sample code.

Comment: I think you should first change  `v_emp_id IN varchar2(12 byte)` to `v_emp_id IN varchar2` and compile this procedure again. And provide detail error you have when execute this procedure. If you just want checking number and string input and not have to use DBMS_ASSERT, you can create some simple verify procedure to do that job.

Comment: Why not use a bind variable? It's important to thoroughly explain why you're not using the standard solution to a problem, so that future readers won't get confused and use this question and answer for the wrong reason.

Comment: The code is written by another person. So, not able to do more changes.

Comment: What you want to achieve through sanitization which you cannot to with others easy numeric value check ? Could you also provide your failure test cases details with input and output ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Oracle 12.2 and higher

If you are on Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can use the [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) function which would be the simplest solution. Your code could potentially look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employee (v_emp_id IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    lv_query   CLOB;
BEGIN
    IF v_emp_id IS NOT NULL AND validate_conversion (v_emp_id AS NUMBER) = 1
    THEN
        lv_query := 'select * from employee where emp_id = ' || v_emp_id;
    ELSE
        --do something here with an invalid number
        null;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

#### Earlier than Oracle 12.2

If you are not on Oracle 12.2 or higher, you can write your own small function to validate that the value is a number.  Using a method similar to what Belayer suggested, just attempt to convert the value to a number using the `TO_NUMBER` function and if it fails, then you know it's not a number. In my example, I have it as a small anonymous block within the code but you can also make it a standalone function if you wish.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employee (v_emp_id IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    lv_query      CLOB;
    l_is_number   BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    --Verify that the parameter is a number
    DECLARE
        l_test_num   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        l_test_num := TO_NUMBER (v_emp_id);
        l_is_number := TRUE;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN VALUE_ERROR
        THEN
            l_is_number := FALSE;
    END;
    --Finished verifying if the parameter is a number

    IF v_emp_id IS NOT NULL AND l_is_number
    THEN
        lv_query := 'select * from employee where emp_id = ' || v_emp_id;
    ELSE
        --do something here with an invalid number
        null;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you cannot change the procedure it means you have no test as that procedure will not compile, so it cannot be executed. However that may be a moot point. You need to define exactly what you mean by "sanitize numeric values". Do you mean validate a string contains a numeric value. If so DBMS_ASSERT will not do that. (Note: The function chooses ENQUOTE_NAME will uppercase the string and put double quotes (") around it thus making it a *valid* object name.) Further your particular validation may require you  define a valid numeric value, is it: an integer, a floating point, is scientific nation permitted, is there a required precision and scale that must be satisfied, etc. As a brute force validation you can simulate the assertion by just convert to number. The following will do that. Like dbms_assert if the assertion is successful it returns the input string. Unlike dbms_assert, however, when the assertion fails it just returns null instead of raising an exception. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=605e134f1b3497e3a2d34192de0b17da).

```
create or replace 
function assert_is_numeric(value_in varchar2)
  return varchar2
is
   not_numeric exception;
   pragma exception_init (not_numeric,-06502);
   l_numeric number;
begin 
   l_numeric := to_number(value_in);
   return value_in; 
exception
   when not_numeric then 
        return null;
end assert_is_numeric;
```